# How to call API (Oauth 1.0)?

Tags: java, api, oauth, intuit-partner-platform, reconnect

I am trying to call this API (Oauth1.0 standard):

https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect

And what I am doing is : (It am working on java)

```
Base64Encoder baseEncoder = Base64Encoder.getInstance();
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect");
            StringBuilder headerReq = new StringBuilder();
            headerReq.append("OAuth ");
            headerReq.append("oauth_token=\"").append(OAUTHTOKEN).append("\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_consumer_key=\"").append(CUNSUMER_KEY).append("\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_signature_method=\"base64\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_signature=\"")          .append(baseEncoder.encode(PropsUtil.get(OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET).getBytes()))
                    .append(baseEncoder.encode("&".getBytes()))            .append(baseEncoder.encode(symmetricEncrypter.decryptData(OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET).getBytes())).append("\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_version=\"1.0\"");
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", headerReq.toString());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            try {
                System.out.println("Responsee::"+ response.getStatusLine());
}
```

And, the response what I am getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlatformResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorMessage>This API requires Authorization.</ErrorMessage>
  <ErrorCode>22</ErrorCode>
```

Can you please suggest me **what I am missing while creating request for Oauth1.0** standard or Please, anyone can provide me the sample code of **Oauth1.0** request example on that standard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PFB working code. Hope it will be useful.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.intuit.ipp.data.Account;
import com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException;
import com.intuit.ipp.net.MethodType;
import com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService;

public class POCWithoutDevkitTest {

    private DataService service;
    private OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer;
    private static String realmID = null;

    public POCWithoutDevkitTest() {
        realmID = "122294642099";
        String consumerKey = "AAAAA";
        String consumerSecret = "BBBBB";
        String accessToken = "CCCCC";
        String accessTokenSecret = "DDDDD";

        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
            this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) throws FMSException {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        }
    }

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/xml");

        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        POCWithoutDevkitTest withoutDevkitClient = new POCWithoutDevkitTest();
        withoutDevkitClient.executeGetRequest("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect");
    }

}
```

**Dependencies**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: I have only consumer key & consumerSecret is it possible to achieve this using only these two?

Comment: Hi @Alekya, No, it is not possible. Using the developer tokens(consumerKey, consumerSecret), you need to generate AccessToken and AccessToken specific to the end-user's resour/realm. You need these 4 tokens to call an API using OAuth1.

Comment: I have a fixed token key & secret, and I have the realm string, how does the realm info become part of the request? A JavaScript OAuth library I've used has an explicit property for realm.

Answer (score 2):

This is the working HTTP GET requestcode in java when all keys are in hand. Hope it does your work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;  //HttpHead, HttpPut, HttpGet, etc...
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpGetRequest {

public static void demo() throws IOException {           
    String consumer_key = "bcd";
    String consumer_secret = "efg";
    String access_token = "rst";
    String access_secret= "xzy";

    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumer_key,
consumer_secret);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(access_token, access_secret);


    String uri = "your url here";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    try {
        consumer.sign(httpget);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,       null, ex);
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));       
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        demo();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have only consumer key & consumerSecret is it possible to achieve this using only these two?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to call Rest API using Oauth-1 and using only consumer key and consumer secret-

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import javax.swing.text.html.FormSubmitEvent;

public class Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken {
    private OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer;

    public Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken() {
        String consumerKey = "my consumer key";
        String consumerSecret = "my consumer secret";
        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret) {
        this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        //oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret("", "");
        oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest)  {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            //throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            //throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            //throw new FMSException(e);
        }
    }

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(FormSubmitEvent.MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/json");

        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url="my url";
        
        Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken withoutDevkitClient = new Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken();
        withoutDevkitClient.executeGetRequest(url);
    }

}
```

Dependencies-

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a builder I created to build the OAuth v1 Authorization header. You may find it useful.

https://gist.github.com/robotdan/33f5834399b6b30fea2ae59e87823e1d

Example usage calling Twitter:

```
String authorizationHeader = new OAuth1AuthorizationHeaderBuilder()
         .withMethod("POST")
         .withURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")
         .withConsumerSecret("twitterConsumerSecret")
         .withTokenSecret("your_oauth_token_secret")
         .withParameter("oauth_consumer_key", "your_consumer_key")
         .withParameter("oauth_token", "your_oauth_token")
         .build()
```