# Quickbooks Online Integration , Authentication Strategy

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to integrate a core java application (middleware) to Quickbooks online , which will post invoices to it .

canu suggest me the integration stategy to follow , as Quickbooks provides two basic authentication methods , Namely :

1 : [SSO Management API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/javascript_functions)

2 : [OAuth Management API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api)

Also in [OAuth Management API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api) , the documents says :

"An authorized access token expires after 180 days.  When this occurs, responses to calls to QuickBooks Data Services and the QuickBooks Online API indicate that the access token is invalid."

which requires A [Reconnect](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect) api to be called, but i can see no example, or proper documentation  for [Reconnect](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect)

Please help !!

Comment: I came across [this][1] 

I think this will solve my problem

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0

Answer (score 2):

> canu suggest me the integration stategy to follow , as Quickbooks provides two basic authentication methods , Namely :

This is not really correct.

- Intuit offers OpenID for establishing identify, and SSO (single sign-on) between your app and QuickBooks. OpenID *does not* get you access to any QuickBooks data.
- Intuit offers OAuth for authorization to QuickBooks data. OAuth *does not* establish identiy or provide any sort of single-sign-on solution.

They serve two very different purposes.

The general rule would be:

- If you are building a SaaS solution and want to be listed on AppCenter.Intuit.com, you must implement both OpenID *and* OAuth.
- Otherwise, just implement OAuth.   (this is often done for one-off custom integrations for a single company, or for apps that aren't a good fit for AppCenter)

It's important that you understand that OAuth and OpenID are two different things with two different purposes. Some recommended reading:

- http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OpenID_vs._pseudo-authentication_using_OAuth

> which requires A Reconnect api to be called, but i can see no example, or proper documentation for Reconnect

The reconnect docs are here -- it's a simple GET call:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect

Comment: Thanks for this @Keith , I clearly understand the difference between OpenID and OAuth, but thanks for describing it in more clear way.The doc for reconnect does not specifies the parameters , which the real concern was.

Comment: There are no parameters for the reconnect call. It's a simple GET request (authenticated by OAuth of course).

Comment: Thanks @Keith, i got the solution here  .. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0