# Call Quickbooks API

Tags: php, xcode, swift, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I want to be able to call the Quickbooks API for a test app I've made on Intuit Developer. The app is made in Xcode, using Swift, here's what I have so far:

```
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1313821405/query?query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20Customer")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in

        println(response)
        println(data)
        println(error)
        if error == nil {
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    println("success")

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error says that "The operation couldn't be completed". I'm doing this in a Sandbox Company, is this the reason why? If I entered a real company ID would it work? Also, how can I use the API?

Comment: Have you authenticated your request using Oauth 1.0 and got the access token and access token secret to make api calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to generate tokens entirely from your mobile app.

Using consumerKey and consumerToken, you can generate accessToken and accessSecret from the OAuthPlayground. https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA PN - After completing C2QB(OAuth) flow, you should use 'App Menu API Test.' option which will show you accessToken and accessSecret.

After getting those 4 tokens, you can make any calls. For that you should use any standard OAuth lib (Swift) like https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift 
PN - I've not tried it yet (I just found it after doing a lil search in net).

PFB post where I'd shared Java code which used signPost OAuth lib. 
You can convert that to Swift (using OAuthSwift or any other suitable lib).
[How to call API (Oauth 1.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0060_authentication_and_authorization

Have you authenticated your request using Oauth 1.0 and got the access token and access token secret to make api calls? You need to have a web page which implements Connect to Quickbooks button and then get these tokens for the QBO company you want to connect to. Then only you can make the calls to the api.

[EDIT]-
Get Request token call-

GET https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_nonce=34562646-ab97-46e1-9aa7-f814d83ef9d1&oauth_consumer_key=qyprd7I5WvVgWDFnPoiBh1ejZn&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1392306961&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0EtvSnzsuumeyib2fiEcnSyu8%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.intuit.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:56:03 GMT

Server: Apache

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Length: 150

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/plain

oauth_token_secret=dXhHHMS1EfdrQ32UabOMscIRWt5bLJNX3ZKljjBc&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=qyprdbwXdWrAt0xM2NgkLlJ79yCp4I2SmDg7tahDBPjA6Wti

Get Access Token-

GET https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token?oauth_verifier=b4skra3&oauth_token=qyprde5fvI7WNOQjTKYLDzTVxJ2dLPTgQEQSPlDVGxEy9wZX&oauth_nonce=f20a5a4b-3635-40a8-92cf-697dfdb07b9d&oauth_consumer_key=qyprd7I5WvVgJZUvWDFnPoiBh1ejZn&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1392397399&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=gEVHttlM8IBAAkmi1dSNJgkKGsI%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.intuit.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 17:03:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 120
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

oauth_token_secret=474gtp6xsFzNJ1EhrrjiHrTH96xXieaRLinjPomA&oauth_token=qyprdNIpWn2oYPupMpeH8Byf9Bhun5rPpIZZtTbNsPyFtbT4

---

[EDIT]-
Raw req and response for making api calls-
POST https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/717093040/query HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: text/plain

Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com

Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="lvprdBmi45KMPO2FnvYtq6KLFTMM7KG0P0PJO3Sm7F3n7pgq",oauth_nonce="e5d6e732-f903-4456-9c5f-58103843c3c6",oauth_consumer_key="qyprd7I5WvVgJZUvWDFnPoiBh1ejZn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1394005668",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="J8qgGZRa4loR6HEtdpAudP1nVpw%3D"

Content-Length: 47
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

Select * From Account

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 07:47:49 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)

HeaderQueryTime: 21

ContextInitTime: 12

HeaderDAOTime: 22

Response-Id: 146f271e-1f23-4842-87ba-ad9fc69fe0a2

Response-App-Time: 196

intuit_tid: 146f271e-1f23-4842-87ba-ad9fc69fe0a2

Connection: close

Content-Type: application/xml

Content-Length: 36683

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-    05T07:47:49.393Z"><QueryResponse maxResults="64" startPosition="1"><Account     status="Pending"><Id>QB:9</Id><SyncToken>7</SyncToken><MetaData>    <CreateTime>2014-03-03T10:56:45Z</CreateTime><LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-    04T14:44:57Z</LastUpdatedTime></MetaData><Name>Name_updatedc4f1a</Name>    <SubAccount>false</SubAccount>   <Description>description_updatedfc6b1</Description><Active>true</Active>    <Classification>Revenue</Classification><AccountType>Income</AccountType>    <AcctNum>49400</AcctNum><CurrentBalance>22654.7</CurrentBalance>   <OnlineBankingEnabled>false</OnlineBankingEnabled></Account></QueryResponse>   </IntuitResponse>
```

Comment: Check the above link on the details of implementing Connect to Quickbooks button in the web page of your application. Check the in-app/within your app flow.

Comment: I'm not making a web page -- I'm making an app, would I have to make a web page?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add a web component/page which handles oauth.

Comment: QBO oauth requires you to implement Appcenter js by using the Connect to Quickbooks button on a web page and oauth swift kit should help you sending the param required for oauth. See the raw request/response example added in my answer above.

Comment: So far, my app can open the Connect to Quickbooks page and get the oauth token and oauth secret token. What link would I then call to access the Quickbooks API? Would it be something like this: https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/396933811 /query?query=SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20Customer&oauth_token_secret=******&oauth_token=******

Comment: Added sample api calls above. You might also want to look at the APIexplorer to see what endpoint need to be called and with what headers.

Comment: You should also refer to the api entity docs here-https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

Comment: The above example I posted above uses Post for query. You need to send he Authorization as a separate header. See the raw request above