# Java - Perform oAuth1.0 authenticated request with given consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret and realm

Tags: java, oauth, httprequest

I am trying to send an http post to a given oAuth1.0 protected endpoint, the owner of the endpoint provided to me:

- consumerKey
- consumerSecret
- accessToken
- accessTokenSecret
- realm

I wrote some code based on [How to call API (Oauth 1.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0)

```
public class HttpAuthPost {
    public HttpAuthPost() {
        realmID = "XXXXXXX";
        String consumerKey = "kjahsdkjhaskdjhaskjdhkajshdkajsd";
        String consumerSecret = "jklahsdkjhaskjdhakjsd";
        String accessToken = "iuyhiuqhwednqkljnd";
        String accessTokenSecret = "oihkhnasdiguqwd56qwd";
        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
        this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
        oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());

    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) throws FMSException {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        }
    }

    public String executeGetRequest(String customURIString, String _content) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpRequest = null;
    //Preparing HttpEntity and populating httpRequest
        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
      // Process response and generate output
      return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I did some tests and I am getting this error: USER_ERROR : header is not NLAuth scheme.

I noticed the realm value is never actually set in the oAuthConsumer configuration, I try to find a way to specify the realm but I have not found a way to do it.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution was actually pretty simple and now that I figured it out it seems obvious. Adding the realm as an additional parameter to the authconsumer worked for me.

Hope this help someone else in the future.

```
public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
  this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
  oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
  oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
  HttpParameters parameters = new HttpParameters();
  parameters.put("realm", realmID);
  oAuthConsumer.setAdditionalParameters(parameters);
}
```

Comment: I am working in the same fashion of code, the only change is I am going to pass URL instead of realmID. Could you please let me know how it can be done. Sorry, I am new to the APIs.