# How to Send a POST request with JSON using Signpost and Apache Http Client

Tags: java, oauth, apache-httpclient-4.x, signpost

I need to send a POST request with an JSON body to an API that uses Oauth 1.0 for it's authentication. To do this I am using Signpost and it's Apache Commons module to sign the request. I have confirmed that a test request with a blank JSON string works by using Postman and having it generate the authentication header for me.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to properly set up the request using Signpost. **Specifically I'm not sure how to add the realm to the request.**

```
  public void sendRequest(String json) {
    String baseUrl = properties.getProperty("apiUrl");
    String consumerKey = properties.getProperty("consumerKey");
    String consumerSecret = properties.getProperty("consumerSecret");
    String tokenKey = properties.getProperty("tokenKey");
    String tokenSecret = properties.getProperty("tokenSecret");
    String realm = properties.getProperty("realm");

    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(tokenKey, tokenSecret);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(baseUrl + "/site/restlet.nl?script=2162&deploy=1");
    System.out.println("requesting " + request.toString());
    consumer.sign(request);

    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    System.out.println("got response " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    client.close();
  }
```

As is this request returns an error from the API that the login request is invalid.

Comment: I do not have the rep to close as duplicate, but I was able to find the answer on how to add the realm in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102784/java-perform-oauth1-0-authenticated-request-with-given-consumerkey-consumerse