# How to call API (Oauth 1.0) in Java ? Getting 401, But working good through Postman

Tags: java, oauth, httprequest, netsuite

I have realm, access token, access token secret, consumer key, and consumer key secret to call third party(Oracle netsuite) rest services. When I call it from the Postman it is working good and getting the valid response.

But when I call the same API in Java with the same details then I am getting 401(Unauthorized) response.
I tried the solutions provided in the questions -

[How to call API (Oauth 1.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0)

[Java - Perform oAuth1.0 authenticated request with given consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret and realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102784/java-perform-oauth1-0-authenticated-request-with-given-consumerkey-consumerse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But still getting 401 error. I will really appreciate it if someone guides me.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: The 401 error means that the authentication data is not correct or not recognized. According your indications the request seem to be well formed

Comment: @AbdelhamidMEDDEB yes. I am using all the data same as which I am using in the postman. Through the postman i am able to access the data.